# How to obtain the representation of a fraction in a particular base (in GP shell)?

Tags: pari-gp

How to obtain the representation of an arbitrary fraction in a particular base? For example, the representation of 1/3 in base 2 should be

```
[[0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...]
```

But when I type `digits(1/3, 2)` in GP shell and press Enter, all I see is the following error:

```
? digits(1/3, 2)
  ***   at top-level: digits(1/3,2)
  ***                 ^-------------
  *** digits: incorrect type in digits (t_FRAC).
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 1/3 is 1/3 and doesn't have a base. If you want to output that in some base to some precision you can multiply by base^precision:

```
digits(floor(1/3 * 2^50), 2)
```

Edited:
A more complete solution:

```
Vec(digits(floor(frac(1/3) * 2^50), 2), -50)
```

The above only deals with the fractional part. The integer part can be obtained with `(1/3)\1`. The number of fractional digits is in this case 50 and appears twice. This could be packaged as a function:

```
fracdigits(f,b,n)=[digits(f\1, b), Vec(digits(floor(frac(f) * b^n), b), -n)]
fracdigits(1/3, 2, 50)
fracdigits(1/8, 2, 50)
```

Comment: This outputs `[1, 0, 1, 0, ...]`, which is incorrect because one zero bit at the beginning is lost: see the output of `binary(0.3333333)`. The correct representation of 1/3 in base 2 is `[[0], [0, 1, 0, 1, ...]`.